# troubleshooting radius auth with okta and AD

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, radius, okta

I am running Amazon Workspaces, and wish to use RADIUS based MFA for login.  MFA would be provided by Okta.

I have an AWS Managed AD with AD Connector connected to it. (I assume this is redundant, but trying to replicate what the on-prem environment would use -- the AD Connector vs connecting to the actual AD).

I have installed the Okta RADIUS agent and it appears its properly talking to Okta via the Radius App, as I have a green status on the Amazon side for it.

I have installed the Okta AD agent on a machine in the same domain as bob, and I am able to import users in to Okta people.

The only thing I have not yet setup is delegated auth, but I've logged in as bob to both AD and Okta using the same PW, so I know they are working with the same PW.  Not sure if I still need delegated auth regardless for this to work?

When I try to login via Workspaces client, I get the user, pw, MFA field, (using Okta Verify for MFA).  But I get access denied when I fill it all in.

If I disable radius on the directory config in Workspaces, it works fine w/o the MFA enabled.

In my Windows Event Log, if I login as the user via the Okta dashboard, I see:

[image]
[image]
[image]

However, when I enable MFA via the Okta Radius Server on the Directory config, I can't login, and instead I get this error in the Event Log:

[image]

I am assuming the devil is in the Account Name in the failed login, where its the fully qualified principal name which is failing, where in the successful login, its just the prefix.

I have tried to mix and match between the Okta Radius app and the Okta Amazon Workspaces app username formats, but I can't get it to just sent the prefix name.  Not even sure if thats the issue, but seems like a smoking gun.

If anyone has this working, if they could share their Okta App configs or other advice for the above would be really appreciated.